# I'm getting error "This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405" when I try test regstering

Tags: html, node.js, express, http, mern

I'm trying to build a signup/login page but when I try to register, I get Http error 405.

Here are my codes:

User.js

```
require("dotenv").config(); // load .env variables
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const { isLoggedIn } = require("./middleware");
const User = require("../models/User");

// Index Route with isLoggedIn middleware
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  const { User } = req.context.models;
  const { username } = req.user;
  // send user data
  res.json({ username });
});

// Register Route
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { User } = req.context.models;
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  // Check if the username already exists
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });

  if (existingUser) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username already exists" });
  }

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

  // Create a new user
  const newUser = new User({ username, email, password });
  await newUser.save();

  // Send a success message
  res.json({ message: "User registered successfully" });
});

// Login Route
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { User } = req.context.models;
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Check if the username and password are valid
  const user = await User.findOne({ username, password });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
  }

  // Create a token
  const token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username }, process.env.SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "7d", // 7 days
  });  

  // Send the token in the response
  res.json({ token });
});

module.exports = router;
```

connection.js

```
require("dotenv").config() // load .env variables
const mongoose = require("mongoose") //import fresh mongoose object
const {log} = require("mercedlogger") // import merced logger

//DESTRUCTURE ENV VARIABLES
const {DATABASE_URL} = process.env 

if (!DATABASE_URL) {
    log.red("DATABASE STATE", "DATABASE_URL is not defined in the environment variables.");
    process.exit(1); // Exit the process with an error code
  }

// CONNECT TO MONGO
mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})

// CONNECTION EVENTS
mongoose.connection
.on("open", () => log.green("DATABASE STATE", "Connection Open"))
.on("close", () => log.magenta("DATABASE STATE", "Connection Open"))
.on("error", (error) => log.red("DATABASE STATE", error))

// EXPORT CONNECTION
module.exports = mongoose
```

.env

```
PORT=4000
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/Mern_login
SECRET="gouda2021"
```

user_login.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Login Form-->
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="curved-shape"></div>
        <div class="curved-shape2"></div>
        <div class = "form-box Login">
            <h2 class="animation" style="--D:0; --S:21;">Login</h2>
            <form action = "/login" method="POST">
                <div class = "input-box animation" style="--D:1; --S:22;">
                    <input type = "text" required>
                    <label for = "">Username</label>
                    <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
                </div>
                <div class = "input-box animation" style="--D:2; --S:23;">
                    <input type = "password" required>
                    <label for = "">Password</label>
                    <i class='bx bxs-lock-alt' ></i>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box animation" style="--D:3; --S:24;">
                    <button class="btn" type = "submit">Login</button>
                </div>
                <div class="regi-link animation" style="--D:4; --S:25;">
                    <p>Don't have an account ? <a href=" #" class="SignUpLink">Sign up</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="info-content Login">
            <h2 class="animation" style="--D:0; --S:20;">Welcome Back!</h2>
            <p class="animation" style="--D:1; --S:21;">PodChord,  On Our Podcast Streaming Platform. We are happy to see you again.</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-box Register">
            <h2 class="animation" style="--li:17; --S:0;">Register</h2>
            <form action = "/register" method="POST">
                <div class = "input-box animation" style="--li:18; --S:1;">
                    <input type = "text" name="username" required>
                    <label for = "">Username</label>
                    <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
                </div>
                <div class = "input-box animation" style="--li:18; --S:1;">
                    <input type = "email" name ="email" required>
                    <label for = "">Email</label>
                    <i class='bx bxs-envelope'></i>
                </div>
                <div class = "input-box animation" style="--li:19; --S:2;">
                    <input type = "password" name="password" required>
                    <label for = "">Password</label>
                    <i class='bx bxs-lock-alt' ></i>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box animation" style="--li:20; --S:3;">
                    <button class="btn" type = "submit">Register</button>
                </div>
                <div class="regi-link animation" style="--li:21; --S:4;">
                    <p>Already have a account ? <a href=" #" class="SignInLink">Login</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="info-content Register">
            <h2 class="animation" style="--li:17; --S:0;">PodChord Welcomes You!</h2>
            <p class="animation" style="--li:18;--S:1;">Start a magical journey of listening with our PodChord, Our Podcast Streaming Platform .</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src = "user_Login.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried checking for any mistakes in my routing but I'm not able to find any. However, I've checked my backend is running properly so it seems to be a problem in routing, so there must be an error I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

For registering the user, try to add the following code:

```js
// Register Route
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { User } = req.context.models;


  // Check if the username already exists
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username:req.body.username });

  if (existingUser) {
    return res.status(200).json({ error: "Username already exists" });
  }
  
  const password = req.body.password;
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);       
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  req.body.password = hashedPassword; 
  
  // Create a new user
  const newUser = new User(req.body);
  await newUser.save();

  // Send a success message
 return res.status(201).json({ message: "User registered successfully" });
});
```